# Juntando Modal Bootstrap com HTML5 History API

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap, api, html5-history

Existe uma maneira de juntar o **modal do Bootstrap** (qualquer versão) com o [API History](http://html5demos.com/history)?

A lógica ficaria assim: Ao abrir o modal a URL na barra de navegação mudaria para `exemplo.com/modal-aberto` e ao fechar o modal a URL voltar ao que era.

Ainda não tenho códigos pois será para alguns projetos futuros.

Exemplo: http://poracaso.ocponline.com.br/ ( Abra um post qualquer da lista. )

Comment: Pergunta... por que motivo, razão ou circunstância tem que mudar a URL ao abrir a modal?

Comment: Eu atualizei o post com um exemplo exato, confira amigo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nunca usei Bootstrap antes, mas eu testei o código e funcionou direitinho:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
    window.history.pushState(null, null, "/modal-aberto");
});

$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
     window.history.replaceState(null, null, "/");
});
```

Lembre-se de alterar o seletor para selecionar o seu modal.

*Editado: Tinha esquecido de remover o '/modal-aberto' ao fechar.*

Comment: Isso será usado em projetos na plataforma Wordpress, vou testar ainda hoje, abraços e obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, creio que montar um exemplo demandaria muito tempo, mas eu já fiz algo assim e posso te ajudar com a lógica.

Primeiro você precisa de qualquer forma de uma linguagem de servidor, no caso do PHP você terá que usar o *.htaccess*. Com ele você tem que criar uma regra que redirecione todas as URL's para o arquivo principal, pois se o usuário atualizar a página ou entrar com a URL manualmente, não sera considerado um `pushState`, por tanto vai redirecionar.

Depois disso você tem que criar uma função que leia a URL normalmento com os atributos de `document.location`. Essa função deve ler a URL e será responsável por executar cada ação referente a URL, como abrir um modal por exemplo.

Depois de criada a função, ela deve ser executada no carregamento da página e em cada troca de URL por `pushState`, para isso você pode chamar ela nos eventos `window.onload` e `window.onpopstate`.

**Observação:**

1 - Se o comportamento for melhor, você pode executar a chamada da função assim que o DOM estiver pronto ao envés de carregado.

2 - O `pushState` ao qual me referia é a função para alterar o URL se redirecionar a página.`

A lógica que usei foi essa.

Comment: Sim, essa lógica é boa, será usada para abrir postagens no Wordpress, isso simplifica/muda algo na sua lógica?

Comment: Muda apenas a questão de que você não precisa mexer no *.htaccess*, você pode usar query vars...

Na documentação do Wordpress procure pela função add_rewrite_rule e por query vars, é uma forma de vocÊ adicionar parâmetros customizados na URL, assim você pode montar pelo *functions.php* regras específicas para sua necessidade. Basta um conhecimento minimo de expressões regulares.

Estes links podem te ajudar: http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule e http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-pass-value-in-wordpress-url

Comment: Acredito que na verdade isso facilite muito! Query vars é uma forma bem simples de trabalhar com essa lógica, eu uso isso para criar navegações com history API para one pages em Wordpress.